# MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter not working with @EnableWebMvc

Tags: java, json, spring

I'm having issues trying to setup JSON marshaling in an XML free config in Spring 3.2.5

Here's my config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.pworld.mvc.controller")
@Import(DatabaseBeansConfig.class)
public class MainServletConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter   {
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("MainServletConfig");
    private List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters; // Cached: this 

        @Override
        void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
          // Note: this overwrites the default message converters.
              converters.addAll(getMessageConverters());
        }

     /**
     * The message converters for the content types we support.
     *
     * @return the message converters; returns the same list on subsequent calls
     */
         private List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> getMessageConverters() {

              if (messageConverters == null) {
                 messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
                 messageConverters.add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
              }
              return messageConverters;
         }
}
```

If I debug this code I can see there's already a `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` in within the default converters so it shouldn't be needed to add another one right?

My controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = CARS_URL + HTML_SUFFIX, 
            method = RequestMethod.POST,
            consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON},
            produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@ResponseBody
public Car handlePagination(Model model, @RequestParam(value = PAG_NUM, required = true) int pagNum,
                                         @RequestParam(value = ITEMS_PER_PAGE, required = true) int itemsPerPage)
    {
        return new Car();
    }
```

So when every time I consume that method I get a

> HTTP Status 406 - Not Acceptable response

I tried returning a plain String and it works, it's only JSON parsing that isn't kicking in...

I have in my classpath:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

What else I'm I missing? I never had a problem getting this to work in an XML `<mvc:annotation-driven />` config....

Request body

```
Request Url: http://localhost:9080/xxx.html?pagNum=1&itemsPerPage=8
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 406
Params: {}
```

Request headers

```
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Connection: keep-alive
Origin: chrome-extension: //rest-console-id
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.154 Safari/537.36
```

And 406 I get from the server

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><title>GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.0  - Error report</title><style type="text/css"><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 406 - Not Acceptable</h1><hr/><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b>Not Acceptable</p><p><b>description</b>The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.</p><hr/><h3>GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.0 </h3></body></html>
```

Spring logs:

```
2014-03-18T15:42:48.790+0000|INFO: TRACE DispatcherServlet - Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@39b08627
2014-03-18T15:42:48.790+0000|INFO: DEBUG DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'main' processing POST request for [/cars.html]
2014-03-18T15:42:48.790+0000|INFO: TRACE DispatcherServlet - Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping@6e078e68] in DispatcherServlet with name 'main'
2014-03-18T15:42:48.790+0000|INFO: DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /cars.html
2014-03-18T15:42:48.790+0000|INFO: DEBUG ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
2014-03-18T15:42:48.791+0000|INFO: DEBUG ResponseStatusExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
2014-03-18T15:42:48.791+0000|INFO: DEBUG DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
2014-03-18T15:42:48.791+0000|INFO: DEBUG DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'main': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2014-03-18T15:42:48.791+0000|INFO: TRACE DispatcherServlet - Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@39b08627
2014-03-18T15:42:48.791+0000|INFO: DEBUG DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
2014-03-18T15:42:48.791+0000|INFO: TRACE AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Publishing event in WebApplicationContext for namespace 'main-servlet': ServletRequestHandledEvent: url=[/cars.html]; client=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]; method=[POST]; servlet=[main]; session=[null]; user=[null]; time=[1ms]; status=[OK]
2014-03-18T15:42:48.791+0000|INFO: TRACE AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Publishing event in Root WebApplicationContext: ServletRequestHandledEvent: url=[/cars.html]; client=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]; method=[POST]; servlet=[main]; session=[null]; user=[null]; time=[1ms]; status=[OK]
```

SOLVED, I used this as a reference: https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc#annotated-account-class

I needed to configure the content negotiation beans in my @Configuration class....

THANKS TO EVERYONE!!

Comment: What does your request look like?

Comment: requests added in the main post

Comment: Yeah, get rid of your `HttpMssageConverter` configuration. Spring will already add `Mapping2JacksonHttpMssageConverter` if jackson is on the classpath.

Comment: Yes I noticed there was a Mapping2JacksonHttpMssageConverter already there, made no difference getting rid of all my code though...

Comment: Can you turn your logs to DEBUG and see what gets logged?

Comment: I just noticed some messages, I posted them

Comment: Show us your web.xml. Put a log statement in your handler method. Is it printed?

Answer (score 0):

First enabled logs of spring on application server and check for more details, but this error happened many times because of missing dependencies,  try to change version of Jackson.

Comment: Im using Glassfish 4.0 and I think I can see the logs you mean, I get all the deployment process logged out and if there's an exception I can see it as well, but nothing happens when my method returns the object, Jackson mappers are just not kicking in...

Comment: check this from reference http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#d0e826

Comment: My Spring logging is working, I can see all the deployment process and exceptions, but I just dont get any error (or any output at all) when I return my object from the method in the controller, just nothing happens